# install grub on mounted filesystem

Tags: grub2, chroot, initrd, rescue-mode

I have booted rescue linux (init ram fs), and mounted `/dev/sda1` on `/mnt/sda1`

`/dev/sda1` is a linux partition, but `/dev/sda` has no mbr.

How can I install grub on mounted filesystem `/mnt/sda1` ?

I tried:

```
mount /dev/sda1 sda1/
mount -t proc /proc proc/
mount -t sysfs sysfs sys
chroot .
```

but then, when i do `grub-install /dev/sda`, I get this error:

```
Installing for i386-pc platform.
grub-install: error: failed to get canonical path of `/dev/sda1'.
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should try one of these options.

**Option 1:** try to install and run boot-repair if you are able to log on to your system.

- Open Terminal and install Boot Repair:

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
>
> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install boot-repair

- You can find it now on dash. Run it from there and press "recommended
  repair" button.
- Restart your system and see if Grub is back to normal.

**Option 2:** try to restore Grub via Live CD

- Create a bootable USB device using a flash drive with an Ubuntu image (same version of
  your OS).
- Boot from it and choose "Try Ubuntu before you install it".
- Open Terminal from your live Ubuntu desktop.
- Mount the partition of your Ubuntu installation. If you are not
  sure about it, launch GParted (included in the Live CD) and find it
  out. It is usually a EXT4 Partition. Replace the **XY** with the drive
  letter, and partition number, for example: *sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt*.

  Now, follow the instructions below:

> sudo mount /dev/sd**XY** /mnt
>
> sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev &&
>
> sudo mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts &&
>
> sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc &&
>
> sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
>
> sudo chroot /mnt

- Now install, check, and update grub. Now it's only necessary to add
  the drive letter (usually a) to replace **X**, for example: *grub-install
  /dev/sda* or *grub-install –recheck /dev/sda*.

  Follow the instructions below:

> grub-install /dev/sd**X**
>
> grub-install --recheck /dev/sd**X**
>
> update-grub

- Now, Grub should be back. Just exit and unmount everything:

> exit && sudo umount /mnt/sys && sudo umount /mnt/proc && sudo umount
> /mnt/dev/pts && sudo umount /mnt/dev && sudo umount /mnt

Now, restart your system and see if that worked.

I've come to this answer using this post as a reference:
https://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd